# deny a text field to inhert Jquery.ui CSS

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

i have a small issue which my text field insist to inhert the CSS of the jquery.ui, i have this textfield inside a Jquery.ui tabs script, which takes its css by add a `class` of the jquery ui tabs, how can i deny this to happen and make the text field doesn't inhert the css.

here is the textfield

```
<input type="text" class="required" maxlength="50" value="" name="class1" />
```

the Jquery.ui tabs give it class when the page loads automatically

```
<input type="text" class="required ui-wizard-content ui-helper-reset ui-state-default" maxlength="50" value="" name="class1">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how jQuery UI works. You could add the input with JavaScript on $(document).ready(). If you add the input after jQuery UI has done all it's binding, you should be able to avoid the issue.

Probably not the best solution (client side form creation), but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Messing with the jQuery UI classes can be tricky most times. The library depends on those heavily. Messing with them might have some unwelcome side effects.

Currently I'm working on a quite large project using jQuery UI and a lot of custom widgets we built around the built-in ones. Te way we solved this problem was more specific CSS to override all the properties we don't like that got inherited from jQuery

For example, you add another CSS file "after" the jQuery UI CSS file in the page, and in there:

```
input.required, input.ui-wizard-content,
 input.ui-helper-reset input.ui-state-default,
 input.ui-helper-reset.ui-state-default {
    /* override properties here */
}
```

It's silly, and there sometimes are a lot of properties to implement, getting specificity right enough (to affect what you want, but nothing else) can take a few tries to get right, but generally this is the leat pain you can get for solving this problem.